# how to make chat application with maintain the chat history in android

Tags: android, chat, android-sqlite, history, quickblox

Hi Friends I am creating chat based application in android. This is first time I am  developing for that I am using external API **QuickBlox API** for android.  I implemented QuickBlox API but my problem is can't able to maintain chat history. so I used local DB that is sqlite. but its not  working fine. chat history not getting properly.

So can you help me how can I maintain  proper DB for chat history from **QuickBlox API**?
OR
Is there anyway to get chat history from **QuickBlox API**/

Thanks in Advance for your Help

Answer (score 1):

Probably, You can save chat history by one of the quickblox module - customObject (http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects). You can create own structure of your db and than retrieve and modify it.